# How to use a different database for Heroku review apps?

Tags: django, heroku, pipeline

I have a deployment pipeline on Heroku which recently started using review apps. This means I have an app - let's call it CI-APP -- which is being created from the master branch.

Every time a pull request is made, a review app is created. We are using Django in our project and so I also added the `migrate` command to the `release` phase in the project, so that database migrations can be done automatically.

Today, a coworker submitted a pull request which contained some database changes. The problem is that the migration was ran, and since review apps seem to be using *the same database* as the app they are suppose to merge to, the migration was applied and now my app CI-APP stopped working...since the code base no longer matches the database structure.

I searched a lot about how to use *completely different databases* for the review apps compared to the parent app, but to no avail (there are some resources mentioning how you can copy db contents, but that is not what I need).

Any suggestion ?

*Update*

Ok, so it seems that Heroku does create a new database for the review app, however: the review app copies all of its environment variables from the parent, including the DATABASE_URL (this seems to be the only way to actually create the review app : https://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku-devcenter-files/article-images/1461071037-initial_set_up_review_apps.png)

I think I can do some black magic in the postdeploy script, but since the database generated url can be something such as HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_{color}_URL, I am not sure how to find it ....

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? It's strange I don't get more discussions related to this on internet. This problem should had been faced by others too or it might be that I'm missing something so obvious here!!! Please let me know what you got. Thanks!!!

Comment: @AnshuKumar, no, we didn't find a solution to this problem. We just decided to remove the `migrate` command from automatically running so now we just run them manually. It's a pretty stable app now, so migrations are rather rare. My suggestion for you would be to do the same and only migrate review apps after you've provisioned a different db to them.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, create the app.json file at the root of your project instead of using the heroku dashboard. In this file, you can specify what environment variables to inherit from the parent.

From the heroku docs:

`"env": {
    "INHERIT_THIS_CONFIG_VAR": {
      "required": true
    },
    "DONT_INHERIT_THIS_CONFIG_VAR": "production"
  },`

This allows you to specify which database you want to use for the review app. Looking at the documentation of the heroku postgres addon (i assume you're using postgres):

> As part of the provisioning process, a DATABASE_URL config var is
>   added to your app’s configuration. This contains the URL your app uses
>   to access the database.

So the database_url config variable will be created by the adddon. You simply need to not put it in the app.json file, and it will be created automatically.

Comment: Hi, could you be more explicit as to how exactly this would solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you do not have the DATABASE_URL set in the Pipeline Settings CONFIG VARS in Heroku either.. if it is set there, then it seems the Review App will use that as the DB link and not the one created when the Review App is created.